# Create Header and Footer in the .docx report using R?

Tags: r, officer

I want the header and footer to repeat in every page of the .docx report. 
Everyone is suggesting use the RMarkdown to get the header and footer. Is it possible using R? 
I am using `Officer` package for .docx report. I want this header & footer in the Clinical reports.

In SAS we can get using the "Header" & "Footer statement". How to get it in the R?

Please help me on this, as am new to R programming.

Thanks & Regards
Vamsi

Comment: https://github.com/davidgohel/officedown/issues/105

Answer (score 1):

Using ‘officer’, you can design a content-empty .docx file with  your header and footer first,  and read it and merge your report, then,    the h&f will repeat in your report.

Comment: Already using officer package and following the same process what you have suggested. Do we have any direct code to get Header and Footer?

Comment: You can edit docx file directly,  which is a zipped file of xml file with folder.

Comment: Do we know how to create a different footer depending on the Section Break of the docx?